# AWT Frame does not handle events

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

The frame opens and close normally but mouse click doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

//Create a frame window that responds to mouse click
public class AWT3 extends Frame {
    String Mmsg="";
    int mouseX=0, mouseY=0;

    public AWT3() {
        addWindowListener(new MyWindowwAdapter(this));
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseeAdapter(this));
    }

public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(Mmsg, mouseX, mouseY);
    }

public static void main(String args[]){
    AWT3 awt3 = new AWT3();
    awt3.setSize(new dimension(500, 500));
    awt3.setTitle("Window framee");
    awt3.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class MyWindowwAdapter extends WindowAdapter{
    AWT3 awt3;
    public MyWindowwAdapter(AWT3 awt3) {
        this.awt3=awt3;
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        awt3.setVisible(false);
    }
}

class MyMouseeAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
AWT3 awt3;
public MyMouseeAdapter(AWT3 awt3) {
    this.awt3=awt3;
}
public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
    awt3.Mmsg="the mouse is clicked";
    awt3.mouseX= me.getX();
    awt3.mouseY=me.getY();``
    awt3.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: and `awt3.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));`

Comment: also has to import the class. import java.awt.Dimension;

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method name should be `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)`
instead of `public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent me)`.

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, this code won't compile. You have an error that you need to fix:

```
awt3.setSize(new dimension(500, 500));
```

to

```
awt3.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
```

and add the proper `import java.awt.Dimension` as pointed out by others.

Another mistake is that `MouseClicked(MouseEvent me)` is not overriding the super class method from `MouseAdapter` as its syntactically wrong (super class method starts with small case). Change it to `mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)` (add the optional `@Override` annotation if you wish).

Comment: *"add the optional **`@Override`** annotation .."*  +1.

Answer (score 0):

**mouseClicked()** is when the mouse button has been pressed and released.

**mousePressed()** is when the mouse button has been pressed.

Your code is working. tested on java 1.7. only the problem I saw, was with out importing the **java.awt.Dimension** class you are trying to create a new dimension(500, 500); although the class name is in simple form you can fix this error and try the code.